# After changing drop down a new div will come and without having the first category value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="radio">
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="specific_content" value="2">
<label for="test2">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="content-form" name="content_form">
            <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
            <option value="category">Category</option>
            <option value="genre">Genre</option>
            <option value="cast">Cast</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control content-type-section" id="content_type" name="content_type" >
            <option value='0'>Select</option>
            <option value="123">Movie</option>
            <option value="321">TV</option>
            <option value="345">Cast</option>
            <option value="987">Genre</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control condition-section" id="sel1" name="conditions" disabled="disabled" onchange="showAnotherSection()">
            <option value='0'>Select</option>
            <option value="1">AND</option>
            <option value="2">OR</option>                                
        </select>
    </div>
</label>
```

The above is my div section which I want to show the same div again after changing the AND/OR dropdown. And if the first div selected Category option then in the newly come div there should n't be the same Category option. Similarly, if Genre chosen in first select then genre will not show again in the newly coming div.

Below is the screenshot for the dropdown fields
[image]

[image]

Comment: please show us how you tried to get the functionality and what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this. I would like to recommend you to not to put lots of weight on the JS side.  However, this can be easily done using [jQuery Clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

> **.clone()** : Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio">
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="specific_content" value="2">
<label for="test2">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="content-form" name="content_form">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
        <option value="category">Category</option>
        <option value="genre">Genre</option>
        <option value="cast">Cast</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control content-type-section" id="content_type" name="content_type" disabled="disabled" onchange="removeDisableFromCondition(this)">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
        <option value="123">Movie</option>
        <option value="321">TV</option>
        <option value="345">Cast</option>
        <option value="987">Genre</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control condition-section" id="sel1" name="conditions" disabled="disabled" onchange="showAnotherSection()">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
        <option value="1">AND</option>
        <option value="2">OR</option>                                
    </select>
</div>
<div id="cloned_copy">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sel1').change(function() {
     var selectedVal = $('#content-form').val();     
     var target = $("#cloned_copy");
     target.empty();
       $("#content-form").clone().appendTo(target);
     $("#cloned_copy option[value='"+ selectedVal +"']").remove();
  });
});
```

See the fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/8kdmhboz/

[image: Fiddle in action]

Comment: I appreciate your answer  but my requirement is something like I will change in the last drop down and as per the change a new div will comes without having the first drop down selected  value

Comment: Can we do the same by selecting 3rd drop down select field. We need 3 drop down should be shown and in first drop down the  selected value shouldn't be there

Comment: @PrakashKumarGuru I have changed my answer and also the fiddle. Now, when you change the 3rd drop down, a drop down will appear without the selected option in the 1st drop down. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: We need completely the 3 drop down and condition is only there shouldn't be the first drop down value which was previously selected(like if we already choosen Catgory, then Category shouldn't be there) and all the 3 drop down are same except the first one

Comment: your answer is right , but where is the other 2 dropdown? We need all the 3 dropdown

Comment: @PrakashKumarGuru Check the fiddle again.

Comment: Sillva, I believe you can solve my problem, as your approach is right

Comment: Awesome @Anjana Silva !!

Comment: But It is coming only one div. If I again change AND/OR after 1 row cloned, next div is not coming, Could you please make it dynamic as per there is 3 select field in first dropdown we can clone upto twice like that

Comment: @PrakashKumarGuru : I am glad it helped. The idea behind this is understanding `jquery clone`. I just wanted to give you the exposure to `jquery clone`. I am afraid you will have to tweak it further to match your exact requirement. If I get a chance, I will update my answer again. Cheers.

Comment: @PrakashKumarGuru Remove `target.empty();` and check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180783/discussion-between-prakash-kumar-guru-and-anjana-silva).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="specific_content" value="2">
    <label for="test2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="content-form" name="content_form">
                <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Select</option>
                <option value="category">Category</option>
                <option value="genre">Genre</option>
                <option value="cast">Cast</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control content-type-section" id="content_type" name="content_type">
                <option selected="">Select</option>
                <option value="123">Movie</option>
                <option value="321">TV</option>
                <option value="345">Cast</option>
                <option value="987">Genre</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control condition-section" id="sel1" name="conditions">
                <option selected="">Select</option>
                <option value="1">AND</option>
                <option value="2">OR</option>                                
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#sel1').on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != "Select" && $(this).val() != "" ) {
        var closestRadioDiv = $(this).closest('div.radio');
        var content_form_value = closestRadioDiv.find('#content-form').val();
        var clonedObj = closestRadioDiv.clone(true, true);
        closestRadioDiv.after(clonedObj);
        if( content_form_value != null && content_form_value != "" ) {
            clonedObj.find('#content-form option[value="'+ content_form_value +'"]').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

check below jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xw9843af/
```

Taken reference from https://api.jquery.com/clone/ where attached events are also getting cloned whenever new element is getting added to page.